# Word categorization with weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka

Can Weka's Naive Bayes be used to categorize words?
For example, I have this training data:

great - P
bad - N
good - P
thanks - P
...

Can I use a Naive Bayes classifier to categorize new words?
Like this:
aweful - N

Comment: For part-of-speech-tagging, most systems use a *hidden Markov Model*. Or probabilistic grammar. In many cases the surrounding context determines the *interpretation* of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do as far as you have some attributes to define the properties of the words. With the information you are providing, it is not enough; and it depends on the kind of problem you face. As an example, in the [CONLL Shared Task 2003](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/), the goal is to determine if a word is in a Named Entity (person, location, etc.), and the prodiced data looks like this:

> U.N.         NNP  I-NP  I-ORG
>
> official     NN   I-NP  O
>
> Ekeus        NNP  I-NP  I-PER
>
> heads        VBZ  I-VP  O
>
> for          IN   I-PP  O
>
> Baghdad      NNP  I-NP  I-LOC
>
> .            .    O     O

As you can see, the words have a number of properties and classes. For instance, `U.N.` is a proper name (`NNP`) and it is in the middle of a Noun Phrase (`I-NP`), and its class is "into a named entity, of type organization" (`I-ORG`). So to predict the tag (the latest feature, you use some other features apart from the word itself. Writing this dataset as an ARFF is trivial.

However WEKA does not fit word categorization problems very well, because you usually make use of the context of the word (previous words, or words and their features in a window around the target word), and there are no simple filters in WEKA to get these kinds of windows. For instance, in the previous example you would need something like:

> U.N.,official,Ekeus,NNP,NN,NNP,I-NP,I-NP,I-NP,I-ORG,O,?

For the second word, in case of training. You are training on official, with all its features, the features of the previous word, and all features from the following word except from the class (as you are reading from left to right). The tag to train on is the next-to-last one (`O`). If you are predicting, you have:

> U.N.,official,Ekeus,NNP,NN,NNP,I-NP,I-NP,I-NP,I-ORG,?,?

But you have to think the features you need, the context you are going to use, and program scripts to get this kind of format and feed it into WEKA. There are not tools to do this out there AFAIK.